# Cross domain cookie with script tag?

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain

I was working on jsonP to send data from a cookie, from a domain A to a domain B. It works well, but my question is not here. I just realize that if I only put a `script` tag on my domain B pointing to my domain A, all the cookies of my domain A are set on my domain B.

Example: I put this tag on my domain B :

```
<script src="http://mydomainA.com/"></script>
```

Only with that, all the cookies of my domain A are set on my domain B.
My question is, is it normal? I thought cookie need some hacks to be cross domain, but i didn't think it was that easy.

Sorry for my bad english, and apologize if my question is stupid or if it has been asked before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you setting the cookies?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that cookies for domain `A` are sent to domain `B`? Can you illustrate the process?

Comment: I can put a ink link pointing any website in my script, all the cookies of this site are set on my domain B. I guess these cookies are set by php or javascript.
I came to this conclusion because if there isn't the script tag including my domain A, i only have the cookies of my domain B. And when i put the link pointing my domain A into my script tag, i have the cookies of my dimain + the cookies of my domain A

Comment: The point is: **where** do you read cookies?

Comment: Firefox, firebug, I guess there is an option set to allow cookies from other website and maybe it's only in Firefox

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies are simply headers in HTTP requests. When the browser requests

```
GET /foo
Host: a.com
```

it receives a HTML document, which contains a `<script>` tag hosted on another domain. So it fires *another* request:

```
GET /script.js
Host: b.com
Cookie: foobarbaz
```

and it can certainly append cookies for domain `b.com`, if any. This means that the last time the browser contacted `b.com`, the HTTP response contained an header like

```
...
Set-Cookie: foobarbaz
...
```

and so subsequent requests to the same domain will maintain the *session*. When the browser requests another resource to `a.com` such as

```
GET /bar.jpeg
Host: a.com
```

the cookie `foobarbaz` set by `b.com` **will not** be sent along with the request, so the scripts on `a.com` don't have access to data from `b.com`.

Comment: I'm curious, would the JavaScript of the page loaded by `a.com` be able to read the contents of the `<script>` tag to snoop the response of the GET request to `b.com`?  For example, if the script tag was loading confidential information with cookies provided with a GET request.  The JavaScript could then submit the response via AJAX to `a.com` could it not?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems that in my testing the information returned from such requests is not accessible in the DOM.  I guess the only danger is that the request itself have side effects, not the response being confidential.

Comment: Yup.  I wasn't sure the essential difference between an AJAX `GET` and a script, link, iframe, or img tag `GET`...  The difference is AJAX can read the response.  Thank for your answer.

Comment: Yes: the fundamental difference is that an AJAX call is fired from the Javascript code, which has total control and could be really dangerous (that's why cross origin requests are not allowed). On the other hand, images and iframes are in the control of the browser, and no client code can intercept HTTP events